# How to setup cmake for a project with several modules including unit test etc

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, googlemock

Ok, it is driving me crazy so I am going to ask you guys for some help.
I am trying to set up a new project which is pretty small at the moment.

To keep it simple, my project structure is something like:
RootProject
- module1 (which is a header only library)
-- include
---module1
----header files (containing templates, which I would like to test)
--test
---testmain.cpp (uses gmock and boost unit test framework)
-CMakeLists.txt (1)
-module2 (another lib, using module1)
--same structure as module 1
CMakeLists.txt (2)

So, I have a root CMakeLists.txt and several CMakeLists.txt for each module.

Root CMakeLists.txt:
    `

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(root) 

# compiler
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")

# cpp flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")
add_definitions(-std=gnu++0x)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
set(BOOST_INCLUDES 
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${Boost_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )

set(BOOST_LIBRARIES
    ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
    ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
    )

# Build with system gmock and embedded gtest
set (GMOCK_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/GMock/gmock-1.6.0/include")
set(GMOCK_LIBRARIES gmock gmock_main)

enable_testing()

# Add sub-directories
add_subdirectory (module1) 
add_subdirectory (module2)
add_subdirectory (module3)

add_executable(root main.cxx)
```

But having a working CMakeLists.txt for module1 let's me get a headache.
Which would be the simplest solution to test the header only module? I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to just pull in the include directories for module1 and do nothing else. In particular, you do not need to create a target for the header-only module:

```
# Add sub-directories
# add_subdirectory (module1) this we don't need
set(MODULE1_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/module1/include")
add_subdirectory (module2)
add_subdirectory (module3)

add_executable(root main.cxx)
set_property(TARGET root APPEND PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${MODULE1_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

An alternative is to define a convenience target for module1. Unfortunately, custom targets caused trouble for me in the past so what I do nowadays is placing an empty `dummy.cpp` in each header-only library and create a static lib out of it. This is only to make CMake happy. This allows you to do the following:

*Module1 CMakeLists*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)  # 2.8.11 needed for target_include_directories

project("module1")

add_library(module1 STATIC dummy.cpp)
target_include_directories(module1 PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
```

*Main CMakeLists*

```
[...]

# Add sub-directories
add_subdirectory (module1) 
add_subdirectory (module2)
add_subdirectory (module3)

add_executable(root main.cxx)
target_link_libraries(root module1)   
# thanks to target_include_directories, this will line 
# pull in the correct include paths from module1 for you
```

This has the advantage that a user does not have to worry at all what the includes or libraries for any module are. You simply pass them all to `target_link_libraries` and it takes care of everything automatically.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, this only solves half of my problem. How do I specify tests for the header only module in my cmake file?
I tried enable_testing(), but this actually doesn't have any effect on the outcome. My test.cpp is not compiled.

Comment: @Caro The test needs to be compiled and linked just as any other executable. Just make your `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries` calls as usual. Once you verified that the test executable compiles and runs as expected, you can add it to CMake by calling [`add_test`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:add_test). This will register the test executable and run it on `make test`.